# PhusionPassenger:Why passenger still kills rails process after set passenger_min_instances = 1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

Our `rails 3.2` app (deployed on `passenger/nginx`) uses gem `ruote`. The `ruote worker` (responsible for writing to database) needs to be kept running all the time for `ruote` to work. What we did is to keep min one instance running all the time by setting in `nginx.conf`:

```
passenger_min_instances 1;
```

However after about `5min` idle time, the `ruote worker` stops responding. After restarting `nginx`, then `ruote worker` starts to work again. We don't know what passenger kills to cause the problem. `enter code here`What else we need to set up in passenger to keep `ruote worker` `running all the time`?

Comment: Could you please help with your nginx-passenger configuration code?

Answer (score 2):

This specifies the minimum number of application processes that should exist for a given application. You should set this option to a non-zero value if you want to avoid potentially long startup times after a website has been idle for an extended period.

Please note that this option does not pre-start application processes during Nginx startup. It just makes sure that when the application is first accessed:

1. at least the given number of processes will be spawned.
2. the given number of processes will be kept around even when processes are being idle cleaned (see passenger_pool_idle_time).

If you want to pre-start application processes during Nginx startup, then you should use the passenger_pre_start directive, possibly in combination with passenger_min_instances. This behavior might seem counter-intuitive at first sight, but passenger_pre_start explains the rationale behind it.

Comment: It did not work - nginx: [emerg] "passenger_pre_start" directive is not allowed here in /opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf:60. Within the server block, there is a location block:  location ~ ^/bt/*$ {
         return 301 /bt/authentify/signin;
         passenger_min_instances 1;
         passenger_pre_start http://xx.xx.xxx.xx/bt;
       }

Comment: The nginx could not be started as well if moving pre_start to the server block (from location block).